# My project vite is giving me a error when I try the command build, the error says "default" is not exported by "src/main.ts"

Tags: javascript, typescript, vite

The cliente vite build all the files for config to me, this is the vite.config.js

```
// Plugins
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import vuetify, { transformAssetUrls } from 'vite-plugin-vuetify'
import ViteFonts from 'unplugin-fonts/vite'

// Utilities
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: { transformAssetUrls }
    }),
    // https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/tree/next/packages/vite-plugin
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
    ViteFonts({
      google: {
        families: [{
          name: 'Roboto',
          styles: 'wght@100;300;400;500;700;900',
        }],
      },
    }),
  ],
  define: { 'process.env': {} },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    },
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.json',
      '.jsx',
      '.mjs',
      '.ts',
      '.tsx',
      '.vue',
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 3535,
    host: true
  }
})
```

This one is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node10",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
       "src/*"
      ]
     }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "src/**/*.js"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```

And this one is tsconfig.node.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node10",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Error message

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ6qS.png)

Someone may help me?

I tried build the files for production, when got the error, the version of vite is v4.5.0
I got this error only doing the command build, on command dev, I got none errors

Comment: without seeing your src/main.ts file, it seems that file does not have a default export. be sure you `export default Component` at the bottom of the file.